# Ember.js embedded records don't work

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a json like

```
{
   "meta":{
      "per":20,
      "page":1,
      "total":2
   },
   "users":[
      {
         "id":119506,
         "first_name":"erglk",
         "last_name":"wfe",
         "email":"bent@exemple.com",
         "groups":[
            {
               "id":5282,
               "name":"test"
            },
            {
               "id":8880,
               "name":"everybody"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":119507,
         "first_name":"eriglk",
         "last_name":"wife",
         "email":"benit@exemple.com",
         "groups":[
            {
               "id":5284,
               "name":"testf"
            },
            {
               "id":8880,
               "name":"everybody"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

For the moment no problem to access the user but I have some difficulties to access the groups array. I've tried `hasMany` and `belongsTo` without success. I had errors. 
I've read few articles about [EmbededRecordMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html) but without any success.

If I declare in my models :

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  first_name: DS.attr('string'),
  last_name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  groups: DS.attr('group')
});
```

I get : **Error while processing route: users Assertion Failed: Unable to find transform for 'group' Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to find transform for 'group'**

Comment: What version of Ember Data and which Adapter / Serializers are you using?

Comment: @TylerIguchi ember 2 and RESTSerializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `DS.attr` to tell Ember that this field is an attribute of a model, and optionally we can specify a type of this attribute. By default, only allowed types are `string`, `number`, `boolean`, and `date`. To support custom type, special class (transform) should be defined. That's what Embers is trying to tell you with this error message. How to define such class, you may find [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Transform.html)

**But**, you don't need to define a custom transform for your task. You need to define a relationship:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  first_name: DS.attr('string'),
  last_name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  groups: DS.hasMany('group', {async: false})
});
```

And use an EmbeddedRecordMixin, as described in official [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html). I can assure you that it works as described there.

Comment: Thanks @gennady-dogaev .I have setup the same RESTSerializer in the doc with inside `attrs: { groups: { embedded: 'always' } }`. I have also at models/group.js : export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
});` But I get when I try to go on the page : `Error while processing route: users Assertion Failed: Passing classes to store methods has been removed. Please pass a dasherized string instead of undefined`. He is waiting for something else...

Comment: the error seems coming from my users route : `export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
   return this.store.query('user', params);
 }
});`

Comment: What adapter do you use? REST or JSON? For your response structure you should use RESTAdapter

Comment: A RESTAdapter. :/ It also works again when I remove the `groups: DS.hasMany('group')` from my model.

Comment: Try to add `isNewSerializerAPI: true` property to your serializer. I'm not sure if it will help, but it worth trying: `export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  isNewSerializerAPI: true,
  attrs: {
    groups: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90509/discussion-between-beni-mio-and-gennady-dogaev).

Comment: This is an issue on ember data. So I'm stuck for the moment : https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3581

Comment: My `  attrs: {
    groups: {
      embedded: 'always'
    }
  },` was simply not is the good serializer. It's now ok. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and figured out a fix given Gennady & Beni's responses, but it still took some time for me to get up and running.

see http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html

I created app/serializers/user.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    isNewSerializerAPI: true,
    attrs: {
        groups: { embedded: 'always' },
    }
});
```

and in app/model/user.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
     groups: DS.hasMany('group', {async: false}),
});
```

And then the model loaded the embedded properties right up!