# Not able to load the hasMany attribute in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I getting error

```
Assertion Failed: Passing classes to store methods has been removed. Please pass a dasherized string instead of undefined.
```

My model (likes)

```
url: attr('string'),
detail_url: attr('string'),
gallery_name: attr('string'),
description: attr('string'),
time: attr('string'),
thumbnail_url: attr('string'),
num_photos: attr('number'),
num_photos_HiFive: attr('number'),
is_following:attr('number'),
karma:attr('number'),
photoThumbs_HiFive:DS.hasMany('thumb'),
```

model (thumb)

```
photo: attr('string'),
photo_url: attr('string'),
```

serializer (same for both )

```
 export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
 isNewSerializerAPI: true,
 primaryKey:'pk',
 normalize: function(typeClass, hash) {
 var fields = Ember.get(typeClass, 'fields');
 fields.forEach(function(field) {
 var payloadField = Ember.String.underscore(field);
  if (field === payloadField) { return; }
  hash[field] = hash[payloadField];
  delete hash[payloadField];
});
return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
 }
 });
```

I am able to receive the response form server.In ember inspector, the "like" model is showing the data.But the "thumb" model is not showing the data.When I comment out the  " photoThumbs_HiFive:DS.hasMany('thumb'),".It works fine but not populated the thumb model.Not sure why its is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. This error often occurs if the backend's response doesn't return a JSON API Document that follows the JSON API specification and the conventions of the examples found on http://jsonapi.org/format. See https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/customizing-serializers/ for more info.

I solved it by following the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34168112/5837307.

Basically, modify your `like` serializer to use `RESTSerializer` instead of `JSONSerializer` and include the embeded attributes in an `attr` object in the serializer.

In your case you do something like:

```
export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
    isNewSerializerAPI: true,
    // . . .
    attrs: {
            photoThumbs_HiFive: { embedded: 'always' }
    }
});
```